# Cognitive search wild card search with special characters

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search, full-text-indexing

We are using cognitive search for a search requirement, and i am unable to do a wildcard search on a field that has special characters.

e.g., If the name field on a document has value - `asdf`, I am able to use search Text `as*` and am getting this document.

However, If the value of this name field on this document is `!asdf`, I am not able to search for it using wild card. I tried searching using the terms `!as*`, `\!as*`, and `/\!as*/`. This only works when i do `!asdf`.

Unable to get the wild card search to work when there are special characters in the field. I am using query type `full`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for Full Lucene mode, you'll see that the exclamation character (!) is considered a special character and it must be escaped with a backslash.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#escaping-special-characters

> Special characters that require escaping include the following: + - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

But, this alone won't work for any property if you use the [Default analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers#default-analyzer). You can test the analyzer directly via REST. If we analyze the string *!asdf* using the standard analyzer, we see that the output is *asdf*.

```
    "tokens": [
    {
        "token": "asdf",
        "startOffset": 1,
        "endOffset": 5,
        "position": 0
    }
]
```

If you want the exclamation character to be included in your index, you have to use an analyzer that do not strip the !-character. See [How to specify analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers#how-to-specify-analyzers) for info on defining an analyzer per property.

To find a suitable analyzer, you can refer to the [Predefined Analyzers Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#predefined-analyzers-reference). Here you'll find a list of preconfigured analyzers. For this particular case, the keyword analyzer will work.

> Treats the entire content of a field as a single token. This is useful
> for data like zip codes, IDs, and some product names.

We can test by uploading two test items. One with a title of "asdf" and another with "!asdf".

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "1",
        "Title": "asdf"
    },
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "2",
        "Title": "!asdf"
    }
]
```

}

Then we query for

```
\!as*
```

(note the escaped ! character) and get 1 document in the result as expected:

```
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 1.0,
        "Id": "2",
        "Title": "!asdf"
    }
```